# Pulling two cols from csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 330k+ rows and 12 columns. I need to put column 1 (numeric ID) and column 3 (text string) into a list or array so I can analyze the data in column 3.

this code worked for me to pull out the third col:

```
for row in csv_strings:
   string1.append(row[2])
```

Can someone point me to the correct class of commands that I can research to get the job done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is the best tool for this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", usecols=[ 0, 2 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
points = []
for row in csv_strings:
    points.append({id: row[0], text: row[2]})
```

You can pull them out into a list of key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

A different answer, using tuples, which ensure immutability and are pretty fast, but less convenient than dictionaries:

```
# build results
results = []
for row in csv_lines:
 results.append((row[0], row[2]))

# Read results
for result in results:
 result[0] # id
 result[1] # string
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv
x,z = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('Data.csv'))
for line in csv_reader:
    x.append(line[0])
    z.append(line[2])
```

This can help u getting data from 1st and 3rd column